# How can I use a generic constraint containing a generic parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I keep getting hung up on variations of this problem. Say that for some reason I want to define a functional `forEach` that takes any type that extends `Iterable`, and returns the *same* type extending `Iterable`. (I'm aware `Array.prototype.forEach` has an `undefined` return, the version I would like to write is different.)

So for example, the type of `forEach([1,2,3], x => whatever(x))` would be `number[]`, *not* `Iterable<number>`.

Here's as far as I've got:

```ts
export function forEach <T, ITER extends Iterable<T>> (
  iter: ITER,
  f: (val: T, index: number, iter: ITER) => unknown
): ITER {
  let i = 0;
  for (const x of iter) {
    f(x, i, iter);
    i++;
  }
  return iter;
}
```

So far so good, but then when I try using it I run into type trouble:

```ts
const result = forEach([1, 2, 3], (x, i, iter) => {
  console.log(x * 2);
});
```

`result` here is a `number[]`, as desired, but the `x` parameter is `unknown` rather than `number`, and the compiler complains when I try multiplying it by two. I've flailed about with `infer` but I just make more of a mess.

Comment: I'm too lazy to write an answer right now but this appears to work: https://tsplay.dev/WGnVXm

Comment: Thank you @Linda, works brilliantly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why `x` is inferred as `unknown`**

It never hurts to double-check what the actual function signature is inferred by the compiler when the generic parameter substitution happens (i.e. when you call the function). Here is how it looks like in your case:

```ts
function forEach<unknown, number[]>(iter: number[], f: (val: unknown, index: number, iter: number[]) => unknown): number[]
```

The compiler is able to figure out that `ITER` is a `number[]` because the type info is present in the array literal you pass in as the first parameter. But the type of `T` is only used as the type of `val` parameter in the callback. Since the callback you pass in is not explicitly typed, type of `x` is, well, unknown, hence `x` is inferred as `unknown`.

**What to do**

Credit for the solution goes entirely to [Linda Paiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431574/linda-paiste), so I will only provide some explanation. The core of it is the following utility that allows us to get the type of values the iterator yields by inferring the type of values and returning it:

```ts
type Iteratee<T extends Iterable<any>> = T extends Iterable<infer I> ? I : never;
```

The rest is simply a matter of passing the iterator type to the generic type parameter and change the type of `val` accordingly:

```ts
export function forEach <ITER extends Iterable<any>> (
  iter: ITER,
  f: (val: Iteratee<ITER>, index: number, iter: ITER) => unknown
): ITER {
  let i = 0;
  for (const x of iter) {
    f(x, i, iter);
    i++;
  }
  return iter;
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGnVXm)

---

Off-note: while looking for an alternative solution, I contemplated using an indexed access type to eventually extract `IteratorReturnResult`'s `value` property type, but currently well-known symbols cannot be used to index types (see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24622)) rendering the approach non-viable.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42543) fixing that, so technically it is going to be possible to unwrap the value, but as `ReturnType` utility itself uses `infer`, the resulting offers no benefits over Linda's version.

Comment: Thank you and Linda for your response and explanation! I feel like I have a better sense for how generic inference works now.